# Initializing a vector with stream iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to initialize a vector using iterators and I'm getting a compiler error basically saying that there's no matching function to call.

The code reads from a file with an istream_iterator and ends with an input sentinel. Then I try to initialize the vector with those two iterators.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include<iterator>

int main()
{
    string from, to;    // get source and target file names
    cin >> from >> to;

    ifstream is(from.c_str()); // open input stream
    ofstream os(to.c_str());   // open output stream

    istream_iterator<string> ii(is);    // make input iterator for stream
    istream_iterator<string> eos;   // input sentinel
    ostream_iterator<string> oo(os,"\n");

    vector<string> words(ii, eos);  // vector initialized from input
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());   // sort the buffer
    copy(words.begin(), words.end(), oo);  // copy buffer to output
}
```

I know I could use the copy function to copy the input stream into the vector, but I read that it can be done this way as well. Can anyone explain why this is not compiling? Thanks.

Compiler error:

```
C:\Users\Alex\C++\stream_iterators.cpp|16|error: no matching function for call to `Vector<String>::Vector(std::istream_iterator<String, char, std::char_traits<char>, ptrdiff_t>&, std::istream_iterator<String, char, std::char_traits<char>, ptrdiff_t>&)'|
```

Edit: It is not a header problem. Std_lib_facilities has all of the needed headers.

Comment: Please copy and paste the compiler error message.

Comment: It compiles without errors for me(except last line). What compiler do you use?

Comment: Why does the error message refer to Vector and String instead of vector and string? What compiler are you using?

Comment: Code::Blocks. The std_lib_facilities header macros vector and string and adds a few facilities to them.

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. There is an error in the last line (no out declared), otherwise it compiles fine. The problem may well be in std_lib_facilities.

Comment: *don't* make macros of vector and string. Don't "add facilities to them". If you need anything added to those classes, do it as free functions.

Comment: It's from the book I'm reading's header file on the website. But I removed it and included the files myself and it worked.

Comment: Just so i can avoid it, what book is that?

Comment: Programming Principle and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: That Bjarne guy knows nothing about C++!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book header had some kind of compliance issues, so I just included the appropriate headers and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<string> words(ii, eos);
```

is an analogue to

```
vector<string> words;
copy( ii, eos, back_inserter(words) );
```

`vector` class has the following constructor:

```
// initialize with range [First, Last)
template<class InputIterator>
   vector(
      InputIterator First,
      InputIterator Last
   );
```

To make your sample compiling you need to include the following:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy
```

Since your identifiers not fully qualified you should add the following:

```
using namespace std;
```

Or fully qualify all STL identifiers.

And to change, I guess,

```
copy(words.begin(), words.end(), out)
```

to

```
copy(words.begin(), words.end(), oo)
```

Comment: Which part? Did you include all required headers?

Comment: std_lib_facilities include all of the required headers except <iterator>, and I've included <iterator> for that.

Comment: std_lib_facilities includes all of these headers

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` in `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"` ?

Comment: Yes. The documentation can be found here. http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Answer (score 0):

Please copy and paste the compiler error. Also you are missing a number of headers such as algorithm and vector. You need a use namespace std declaration or use std:: to access the STL classes.

Once you provide more information we can give you more advice.

Update: why is your error message referring to "Vector" (with capital), not vector (lower case)?

Comment: These headers are included in the std_lib_facilities header.

Answer (score 0):

The Vector class in [std_lib_facilities.h](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) defines three constructors, but not one which accepts a pair of iterators. You can go ahead and add that to the header:

```
template <class Iter>
Vector(Iter from, Iter to): std::vector<T>(from, to) {}
```

With this header you'll need to take into account that this is for hand-holding. operator[] in a real std::vector is not supposed to do range-checking. (Why not just teach beginners to use vector::at instead, until they get the idea that it might be better to stay in bounds...?)